# Redirección a página con contacto después de mensaje de éxito (PHP y HTML) [Resuelto]

Tags: php

no soy programadora pero le he hecho la lucha, tengo un código en PHP y HTML (solo he agregado las etiquetas para que lea el php), tengo un formulario y quiero que después de enviar el mensaje, ya sea que el mensaje de éxito aparezca dentro de la página y posteriormente muestre la página de contacto.

Ya que cuando ejecuto el PHP, realizo el formulario, me envía el mensaje de éxito pero sin formato.

Código de la página principal:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es_MX">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

    <!--Inicio etiquetas seo-->
<meta name="Description" content="Contáctanos. Laboratorios de Análisis Clínicos con 75 sucursales en Tabasco, Chiapas y Veracruz, con 37 años de experiencia. Precisión que da confianza.">
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">

    <!--etiquetas funcionamiento-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laboratorios Chontalpa :: Contacto</title>
<link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">   
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/fuentes.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <!--favicon-->          
            <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<!--Seguimiento de Google Analytics-->
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-102075320-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-102075320-1');
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <!--Contenedor-->
    <div class="container-fluid">

    <!--Header-->
        <header class="row">

            <!--barrasuperior-->
            <div id="topbar" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right text-right" style="background: white"> Atención teléfonica las 24 hrs: <a href="tel:018005015555" style="color: #00843d"><b><i>01 800 501 55 55</i></b></a>          
            </div>


            <!--logo-->
            <div id="logo" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background:white">
                <a href="index.html">  
                    <img src="images/LOGO.png" alt="logo" class="center-block"> </a>
            </div>

            <!--menumovil-->
        <div id="botoneraMovil" class="navbar-header navbar-inverse">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#botonera">

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>

       </div>

        <nav id="botonera" class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="servicios.html"><b>Servicios</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="localizatusucursal.php"><b>Localiza tu Sucursal</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="consultaderesultados.html"><b>Consulta de Resultados</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="facturacionelectronica.html"><b>Facturación Electrónica</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="medicos.html"><b>Médicos</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="contacto.html"><b>Contacto</b></a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>

</header>




    <!--Título-->
        <div id="titulo" class="row">
            <div id="tituloppal" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 center-block"> <h1><strong>Contacto</strong></h1>

            </div>
        </div>


        <!--Contenido Formularios-->

        <div class="page">

   <!--  <h3 class="tit_secc">Contáctanos  </h3> -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"></div>
     <div class="box_contact rc6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
     <a href="#" id="paciente"><div class="box_contact_izq pacientes rc6006 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><br /><img src="images/contacto/contact_pacientes.png" alt="Pacientes" width="145px"></div></a>
     <script>
             $('#paciente').click(function(){
             $('#pacientes').show(100);
             $('#empresas').hide(100);
             $('#medicos').hide(100);});

        </script>
     <a href="#" id="empresa"><div class="box_contact_mid empresas col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><br /><img src="images/contacto/contact_empresas.png" alt="Empresas" width="145px"></div></a>
     <script>
             $('#empresa').click(function(){
             $('#empresas').show(100);
             $('#pacientes').hide(100);
             $('#medicos').hide(100);});

        </script>
     <a href="#" id="medico"><div class="box_contact_der medicos rc0660 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="align-content: center"><br /><img src="images/contacto/contact_medicos.png" alt="Médicos" width="145px"></div></a>
     <script>
             $('#medico').click(function(){
             $('#medicos').show(100);
             $('#empresas').hide(100);
             $('#pacientes').hide(100);});

        </script>
            </div><br /> 

<div class="box_contact_forms col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 2%" align="center" id="result"> 


  <div id="pacientes">


   <table align="center">
    <tr>
     <td>

     <form action="enviar_email.php" method="post" id="frmContact1" name="frmContact1"  class="" >  
     <input type="hidden" name="formulario" value="pacientes">
      <table align="center">
        <tr>
          <td>Nombre: </td>
          <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="validate[required] form-control "  required /></td>
          <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left">Localidad:</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="localidad" name="localidad" class="validate[required] form-control " required /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Télefono:</td>
          <td><input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" class="form-control validate[required] " required /></td>
          <td></td>
          <td colspan="2" align="left"  >Comentario o Sugerencia:</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Celular:</td>
          <td><input type="tel" id="cel" name="cel" class="validate[required] form-control" required /></td>
          <td></td>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
           <textarea id="message" name="message"  class=" validate[required] form-control" style="resize:vertical" required ></textarea>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>E-mail:</td>
          <td><input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="validate[required,custom[email]] form-control" required /></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
         </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td align="center" colspan="6">
           <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn1" id="enviarContact1" >Enviar comentario</button>
        <!--  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit Button"> -->
          </td>
         </tr> 
        </table>
      </form>
      </td>
     </tr>



    </table>   

   </div>


            </div><!--Eliminar si -->

    <div id="empresas" style="display:none;">


   <table align="center">
    <tr>
     <td>

     <form action="enviar_email.php" method="post" id="frmContact2" name="frmContact2"  class="" >  
     <input type="hidden" name="formulario" value="empresas">
      <table align="center">
        <tr>
          <td align="left">Nombre: </td>
          <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name_e" class="validate[required] form-control "  /></td>
          <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left">E-mail:</td>
          <td><input type="email" id="email" name="email_e" class="validate[required,custom[email]] form-control" /></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="bottom">Nombre de la empresa:
          <input  type="text" class="validate[required] form-control form-control_1 " id="emp" name="emp_e"  /></td>
          <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left">Localidad:</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="localidad" name="localidad_e" class="validate[required] form-control " /></td>

         </tr>

         <tr>
          <td align="left">Télefono:</td>
          <td><input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel_e" class="validate[required] form-control" /></td>
          <td></td>
          <td colspan="2" align="left"  >Comentario o Sugerencia:</td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top">Celular:</td>
          <td valign="top"><input type="tel" id="cel" name="cel_e" class="validate[required] form-control" /></td>

          <td></td>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" valign="top">
           <textarea id="message" name="message_e"  class=" validate[required] form-control" style="resize:none" ></textarea>
          </td>          
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td></td>
         </tr>
        <tr> 

          <td align="center" colspan="6">
           <button  class="btn btn-default btn1" id="enviarContact2" >Enviar comentario</button> 
          </td>
         </tr> 
        </table>
      </form>
      </td>
     </tr>



    </table>   


    </div>




    <div id="medicos" style="display:none;">


   <table align="center">
    <tr>
     <td>

     <form action="enviar_email.php" method="post" id="frmContact3" name="frmContact3"  class="" > 
     <input type="hidden" name="formulario" value="medicos">
   <!--  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmAddArtic" name="frmAddArtic" class="form-horizontal" role="form" > -->
      <table align="center">
        <tr>
          <td align="left">Nombre: </td>
          <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name_m" class="validate[required] form-control "  /></td>
          <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left">Localidad:</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="localidad" name="localidad_m" class="validate[required] form-control " /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td align="left" colspan="2">Especialidad: <input type="text" id="especialidad" name="especialidad_m" class="validate[required] form-control form-control_2" /></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Email:</td>
          <td><input type="email" id="email" name="email_m" class="validate[required,custom[email]] form-control" /></td>
         </tr>

          <tr>
          <td align="left" colspan="2" >
          Dirección consultorio: <input type="text" id="consult_dir" name="consult_dir_m" class="validate[required] form-control form-control_3" /></td>
          <td></td> 
          <td colspan="2" align="left"  >Comentario o Sugerencia:</td>  
         </tr>

         <tr>
          <td align="left">Télefono:</td>
          <td><input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel_m" class="form-control validate[required] " /></td>
          <td></td>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
           <textarea id="message" name="message_m"  class=" validate[required] form-control" style="resize:vertical" ></textarea>
          </td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
          <td align="left">Celular:</td>
          <td><input type="tel" id="cel" name="cel_m" class="validate[required] form-control" /></td>
          <td></td>

         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td></td>
         </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td align="center" colspan="6">
           <button  class="btn btn-default btn1" id="enviarContact3" >Enviar comentario</button> 
          </td>
         </tr> 
        </table>
      </form>
      </td>
     </tr>



    </table>   

    </div>    





  </div>


 </div> 

 <br>

        <!--Contenido Formularios-->





<section id="pie" class="row"><!--pie de página-->
                <aside class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 text-center" style="margin-top:20px"><!--aside izquierdo-->
                    <h4><strong>Laboratorios Centrales</strong></h4>

                    <div id="labvilla" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="border: none"> 
                     Villahermosa, Tab. <br>
                    Carr. Villahermosa-Teapa Km. 4+150 <br>
                    Col. Plutarco Elías Calles<br>
                    (993) 358 27 00<br>
                    (993) 314 00 76
                    </div><!--Laboratorio Villa-->
                    <div id="labcoatza" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="border:none">
                    Coatzacoalcos, Ver.<br>
                    Av. López Mateos 501<br>
                    Col. Petrolera C.P. 96500<br>
                    01 (921) 214 43 25<br>
                    01 (921) 214 65 58
                    </div><!--Laboratorio Coatza-->

                    <div id="redes" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="border:none"><!--redes sociales-->
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/laboratorioschontalpa" target="_blank"><img src="images/icon-fb.svg" width="30px" alt="Facebook"> </a>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/laboratorioschontalpa" target="_blank"> <img src="images/icon-in.svg" width="30px" alt="Instagram"></a>
                    </div><!--redes sociales-->
                </aside><!--aside izquierdo-->


                <aside class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5"><!--aside derecho-->
                    <div id="37a" style="border:none"><!--37años-->
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p><img src="images/37_a.gif" width="108" height="65" class="img-responsive" style="align-content: center" alt="37a"></p>
                    </div><!--37años-->

                    <div id="precision" style="border:none"><!--precision que da confianza-->
                        <img src="images/Precision-que-da-confianza.png" alt="Precisión" width="245" height="25" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>

                    <div id="links_rapidos" class="text-center" style="border:none">
                      <a target="_blank" href="nuestra_empresa.html" id="nuestra_empresa">Nuestra Empresa </a> |
                      <a target="_blank" href="bolsa_trabajo.html" id="bolsa_de_trabajo">Bolsa de trabajo</a> | 
                      <a target="_blank" href="aviso_privacidad.html" id="aviso_de_privacidad">Aviso de Privacidad |</a>
                      <a target="_blank" href="terminosycondiciones.html" id="terminos_y_condiciones">Términos y condiciones</a> | 
                     <br>
                    </div><!--Links rápidos-->
                </aside><!--aside derecho-->

            <div id="copyright" class="row"><!--div copyright-->
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center text-white">
                        <p>&copy;2018. Todos los derechos reservados. <a href="http://www.laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx" target="_blank" style="color: #008430">Laboratorios Chontalpa. </a></p>
                    </div><!--div clase copyright-->
                </div><!--div copyright-->
            </section><!--pie de página-->

        </div><!--div contenedor principal-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Código del contacto (el que ejecuta la función)

```
<?php

    require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

    $formulario = $_POST['formulario'];

    switch ($formulario) {
        case "pacientes":
            try {

                    $nombre_p = $_POST['name']; 
                    $localidad_p = $_POST['localidad'];
                    $tel_p = $_POST['tel']; 
                    $cel_p = $_POST['cel']; 
                    $message_p = $_POST['message']; 
                    $email_p = $_POST['email'];

                    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //Nueva instancia, con las excepciones habilitadas
                    $body = '<p> Nombre: '. $nombre_p .'<br>'.'Localidad: '.$localidad_p.'<br>'.'Telefono: '.$tel_p.'<br>'.'Celular: '.$cel_p.'<br>'.'Email: '.$email_p.'<br><br>'.'Comentarios: '.$message_p.'</p>';
                    $body             = preg_replace('/\\\\/','', $body); //Escapar backslashes
                    $mail->IsSMTP();                           // Usamos el metodo SMTP de la clase PHPMailer
                    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // habilitado SMTP autentificación
                    $mail->Port       = 587;                    // puerto del server SMTP
                    $mail->Host       = "hv22svg070.neubox.net"; // SMTP server
                    $mail->Username   = "atencionaclientes@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx";     // SMTP server Usuario
                    $mail->Password   = "4t3nc10nclientes";            // SMTP server password
                    $mail->From       = "soporte@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx"; //Remitente de Correo
                    $mail->FromName   = "Atencion a clientes"; //Nombre del remitente
                    $to = "rlopez@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx";
                    $mail->AddAddress($to);
                    $mail->Subject  = "Contacto de Pacientes"; //Asunto del correo
                    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
                    $mail->IsHTML(true); // Enviar como HTML
                    $mail->Send();//Enviar
                    echo 'El Mensaje ha sido enviado. <br> Pronto nos pondremos en contacto con usted.';
                } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
                    echo $e->errorMessage();//Mensaje de error si se produciera.
                }

               break;



        case "empresas":
            try {
                    $nombre_e = $_POST['name_e']; 
                    $empresa_e = $_POST['emp_e']; 
                    $localidad_e = $_POST['localidad_e'];
                    $tel_e = $_POST['tel_e']; 
                    $cel_e = $_POST['cel_e']; 
                    $message_e = $_POST['message_e']; 
                    $email_e = $_POST['email_e'];


                    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //Nueva instancia, con las excepciones habilitadas
                    $body = '<p> Nombre: '. $nombre_e .'<br>'.'Nombre de la empresa: '.$empresa_e.'<br>'.'Localidad: '.$localidad_e.'<br>'.'Telefono: '.$tel_e.'<br>'.'Celular: '.$cel_e.'<br>'.'Email: '.$email_e.'<br><br>'.'Comentarios: '.$message_e.'</p>';
                    $body             = preg_replace('/\\\\/','', $body); //Escapar backslashes
                    $mail->IsSMTP();                           // Usamos el metodo SMTP de la clase PHPMailer
                    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // habilitado SMTP autentificación
                    $mail->Port       = 587;                    // puerto del server SMTP
                    $mail->Host       = "hv22svg070.neubox.net"; // SMTP server
                    $mail->Username   = "atencionaclientes@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx";     // SMTP server Usuario
                    $mail->Password   = "4t3nc10nclientes";            // SMTP server password
                    $mail->From       = "soporte@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx"; //Remitente de Correo
                    $mail->FromName   = "Atencion a Empresas"; //Nombre del remitente
                    $to = "rcamacho@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx";
                    $to2= "jnavarrete@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx"; //Para quien se le va enviar
                    $mail->AddAddress($to);
                    $mail->AddAddress($to2);
                    $mail->Subject  = "Contacto de Empresas"; //Asunto del correo
                    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
                    $mail->IsHTML(true); // Enviar como HTML
                    $mail->Send();//Enviar
                    echo 'El Mensaje ha sido enviado. <br> Pronto nos pondremos en contacto con usted.';
                } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
                    echo $e->errorMessage();//Mensaje de error si se produciera.
                }

            break;
        case "medicos":
            try {

                    $nombre_m = $_POST['name_m']; 
                    $especialidad_m = $_POST['especialidad_m']; 
                    $dirConsultorio_m = $_POST['consult_dir_m'];
                    $localidad_m = $_POST['localidad_m'];
                    $tel_m = $_POST['tel_m']; 
                    $cel_m = $_POST['cel_m']; 
                    $message_m = $_POST['message_m']; 
                    $email_m = $_POST['email_m'];

                    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //Nueva instancia, con las excepciones habilitadas
                    $body = '<p> Nombre: '. $nombre_m .'<br>'.'Especialidad: '.$especialidad_m.'<br>'.'Direccion del Consultorio: '.$dirConsultorio_m.'<br>'.'Localidad: '.$localidad_m.'<br>'.'Telefono: '.$tel_m.'<br>'.'Celular: '.$cel_m.'<br>'.'Email: '.$email_m.'<br><br>'.'Comentarios: '.$message_m.'</p>';
                    $body             = preg_replace('/\\\\/','', $body); //Escapar backslashes
                    $mail->IsSMTP();                           // Usamos el metodo SMTP de la clase PHPMailer
                    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // habilitado SMTP autentificación
                    $mail->Port       = 587;                    // puerto del server SMTP
                    $mail->Host       = "hv22svg070.neubox.net"; // SMTP server
                    $mail->Username   = "atencionaclientes@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx";     // SMTP server Usuario
                    $mail->Password   = "4t3nc10nclientes";            // SMTP server password
                    $mail->From       = "soporte@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx"; //Remitente de Correo
                    $mail->FromName   = "Atencion a Médicos"; //Nombre del remitente
                    $to = "atencionamedicos@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx";
                    $to2= "jnavarrete@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx";
                    $to3= "alira@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx";
                    $to4= "aleon@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx";
                    $to5= "rweber@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx"; //Para quien se le va enviar
                    $mail->AddAddress($to);
                    $mail->AddAddress($to2);
                    $mail->AddAddress($to3);
                    $mail->AddAddress($to4);
                    $mail->AddAddress($to5);
                    $mail->Subject  = "Contacto de Medicos"; //Asunto del correo
                    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
                    $mail->IsHTML(true); // Enviar como HTML
                    $mail->Send();//Enviar
                    echo 'El Mensaje ha sido enviado. <br> Pronto nos pondremos en contacto con usted.';
                } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
                    echo $e->errorMessage();//Mensaje de error si se produciera.
                };

            break;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: cuando aprietas el botón enviar comentario, a que .php se esta llendo?

Comment: Sí, me aparece el "Mensaje enviado con éxito" lo que quiero es que ese mensaje me aparezca en la misma página o que al menos me redireccione a la misma, para que no pierda los estilos...

Comment: Le agregué el código php de la función a la página que tiene el formulario, pero al enviar, me marca este mensaje: 
Warning: require_once(class.smtp.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 968

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'class.smtp.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 968

Comment: pero ese es otro error, a nivel de conf. del servidor de correos. te están llegando los correos o consultas??

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La pregunta esta bien formulada. Lo unico que te pido es que si te piden informacion, la agregues a la pregunta y no en comentarios. usa el boton [edit] para ello.

Comment: Sí, los correos sí me llegan, en todos los formatos

Lo que hice fue en el código de la función, solo agregar el estilo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolví, así como me dijiste ahora funcionó, no funcionaba pero hice una pequeña corrección. Dejo aquí el código por si a alguien le sirve. ¡Muchas gracias!

Contacto.php:

```
<form action="envio_form.php" method="post" id="frmContact1" name="frmContact1"  class="" >  
     <input type="hidden" name="formulario" value="pacientes">
      <table align="center">
        <tr>
          <td>Nombre: </td>
          <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="validate[required] form-control "  required /></td>
          <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left">Localidad:</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="localidad" name="localidad" class="validate[required] form-control " required /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Télefono:</td>
          <td><input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" class="form-control validate[required] " required /></td>
          <td></td>
          <td colspan="2" align="left"  >Comentario o Sugerencia:</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Celular:</td>
          <td><input type="tel" id="cel" name="cel" class="validate[required] form-control" required /></td>
          <td></td>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
           <textarea id="message" name="message"  class=" validate[required] form-control" style="resize:vertical" required ></textarea>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>E-mail:</td>
          <td><input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="validate[required,custom[email]] form-control" required /></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
         </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td align="center" colspan="6">
           <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn1" id="enviarContact1" >Enviar comentario</button>
        <!--  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit Button"> -->
          </td>
         </tr> 
        </table>
      </form>
      </td>
     </tr>



    </table>   

   </div>
```

envio_form.php:

(En la primera parte dejé el mismo header que en mi página de contacto, en la parte del contenedor de la página (donde tengo el formulario), coloqué el php de la función:

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

$formulario = $_POST['formulario'];



                $nombre_p = $_POST['name']; 
                $localidad_p = $_POST['localidad'];
                $tel_p = $_POST['tel']; 
                $cel_p = $_POST['cel']; 
                $message_p = $_POST['message']; 
                $email_p = $_POST['email'];

                $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //Nueva instancia, con las excepciones habilitadas
                $body = '<p> Nombre: '. $nombre_p .'<br>'.'Localidad: '.$localidad_p.'<br>'.'Telefono: '.$tel_p.'<br>'.'Celular: '.$cel_p.'<br>'.'Email: '.$email_p.'<br><br>'.'Comentarios: '.$message_p.'</p>';
                $body             = preg_replace('/\\\\/','', $body); //Escapar backslashes
                $mail->IsSMTP();                           // Usamos el metodo SMTP de la clase PHPMailer
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // habilitado SMTP autentificación
                $mail->Port       = 587;                    // puerto del server SMTP
                $mail->Host       = "hv22svg070.neubox.net"; // SMTP server
                $mail->Username   = "atencionaclientes@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx";     // SMTP server Usuario
                $mail->Password   = "4t3nc10nclientes";            // SMTP server password
                $mail->From       = "soporte@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx"; //Remitente de Correo
                $mail->FromName   = "Atencion a clientes"; //Nombre del remitente
                $to = "rlopez@laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx";
                $mail->AddAddress($to);
                $mail->Subject  = "Contacto de Pacientes"; //Asunto del correo
                $mail->MsgHTML($body);
                $mail->IsHTML(true); // Enviar como HTML
                $mail->Send();//Enviar
                echo 'El Mensaje ha sido enviado. <br> Pronto nos pondremos en contacto con usted.';
            } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
                echo $e->errorMessage();//Mensaje de error si se produciera.
            }

?>
```

Aquí abajo vienen los otros switch (porque tengo tres formularios), se puede quitar nada más el código que hace el cambio y después agregué el código del pie de página y ya.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es cambiar la redireccion (de esa pagina) al home de tu portal, primero debes identificar cual es el .php que esta haciendo grabando los datos y enviándote a .php que te muestra el mensaje de "éxito".
una ves identificado el php puedes:

1) arreglar el formato css o html de tu .php mensaje exito.

2) rediccionar el php a otro php.

En caso que tomes la acción 2 el código de redireccion que debes insertar seria:

```
 <?php
 header('Location: ../index.php');
 ?>
```

la ruta dependerá de donde estes parada en tu sitio raiz.

Comment: Ya lo intenté, al usar Location, ya no me aparece el mensaje de éxito (aunque sí redirige). Intenté un nuevo php y me marca este error: Warning: require_once(class.smtp.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 968

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'class.smtp.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 968

Comment: eso ya es otro error, como te indique de la conf. servidor de correo

Answer (score 0):

Un modo de hacer lo que quieres es enviar de nuevo a la página donde tienes el formulario añadiendo en la url una variable que indique si has tenido o no éxito en el envío de tus formularios.

Para ello das valor a la variable en los diferentes try-catch, por ejemplo vamos a darle valor 1 si es correcto y 0 si falló:

```
try {
   .....
   $mail->Send();//Enviar
   $envio_correcto = 1;
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();//Mensaje de error si se produciera.
    $envio_correcto = 0;
}
```

Y una vez que acabas los casos en este mismo archivo añades depués de cerrar la etiqueta php un script que te devuelve a la página de inicio con la variable:

```
<script>
window.location="http://www.miweb.com/pagina-formulario.php?env=<?php echo $envio_correcto;?>";
</script>
```

Y en tu pagina-formulario procesas esta variable y muestras el mensaje en función de su valor donde quieras que se muestre, generalmete se coloca por encima del fomulario.

```
<?php if isset($_REQUEST['env']) {
   //tenemos la variable, mostramos mensaje
   if ($_REQUEST['env']==1) {
     echo 'El Mensaje ha sido enviado. <br> Pronto nos pondremos en contacto con usted.';
   } else {
     //mensaje de error
   }
} ?>
```

Comment: Yo creo que esta era la opción que yo estaba buscando, muchas gracias

Comment: No hay de que, para eso estamos